# How to append an pre-filled textarea content using fillIn

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-testing

I have a textarea which is already filled in with value using fillIn function. But now I want to append the same textarea with another character '@'. But when I tried using fillIn again; it rewrites the textarea. How can I append the text. I need it to be in two step process.

HTML:

```html
<textarea data-test-id='descriptor'></textarea>
```

Test:

```js
test('testing-fillIn', async function(assert){
await fillIn(testSelector('descriptor'), 'First text ');
await fillIn(testSelector('descriptor'), '@');
});
```

The output should be : First text @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
test('testing-fillIn', async function(assert){
await fillIn(testSelector('descriptor'), 'First text ');
var textVal =document.getElementById('textArea').val();
await fillIn(testSelector('descriptor'), textVal+'@');
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea" data-test-id='descriptor'></textarea>
```

Comment: You can use javascript to get the previous val of textArea and then append it to new val